# App Engine Flex Error Server

Tags: google-app-engine

first of all I would like to apologize for the written form but I do not speak fluent English and I am using google translator. I have a project (Webservices) in the glcoud console using the app engine, when this project receives requests through clients with 4G connection the server starts to display error "Error: Server Error
The server encountered a temporary error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds. "
When the same clients make requests via wifi or 3G the app engine works normally, my ambience of the app engine is the flex I do not use balancer http configured. What could be happening?

Comment: Are language are you using Python/Java/...?

Answer (score 0):

It can be:

1. Networking issue:

   - > This kind of difference with mobile/desktop is often related to IPv6. It is possible that your app is trying to parse the user's IP address and assuming it's IPv4, so it fails from IPv6 clients? We could test it knowing the URL of your app.
   - What zone is your server deployed?
   - Is it permanent error response on 4G or only occurs sometimes?
2. Or error in the code from your app.

To make sure the error is NOT in your application, please try to deploy the sample HelloWorld application as described in the [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/quickstart).

If that works correctly it means you have problem with your code:

> You can start debugging your own code. You can check the logs in [Stackdriver](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/logging) and take a look at the App Engine dashboard.
>   Additionally, you can try [Stackdriver Debugger](https://cloud.google.com/debugger/docs/setup/dotnet) for a closer look at the code.